# how to scroll to accurate block with iScroll plugin for angularJs

Tags: angularjs, iscroll

How to scroll to the block with the id?
iScroll use css rule transforms to scroll content, but this event is impossible to catch.

Comment: Or maybe someone knows good scroll plugin for Angular, which have function scrollTo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iScroll brings a function with it: http://iscrolljs.com/#indicators (scroll down to "Scrolling programmatically")

You can scroll to a specific element (like the block with ID you mentioned) or to a specific position. Position can be x or y from left top edge of the plugin. With jQuery, you can get that position via $('#id').position().left / $('#id').position().top.

Answer (score 0):

anchorScroll:
inject  $anchorScroll,$location in controller.
give the id(Scroll)where to scroll in html file.
and paste the code in controller.
           $scope.scrollTo = function () {
        $location.hash('Scroll');
        $anchorScroll();

```
}
```

and where the function want that time we call the function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it does not work with the plugin iSkroll. This plugin scrolled content with change css rule translate. Standard methods for scrolling do not work here.